# Is there any way to undo the changes of code in salesforce org?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-chatter

I accidentally deployed the code to my sandbox. My changes override other people's changes. So is there any way to undo this? Please help

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to undo this.

In order to avoid this problem, it is critical to use source control, and for developers to execute work in isolated environments. That can be a scratch org (best), or a developer sandbox. Doing development in shared environments is a very bad practice and with the tools available in 2022 there's just no excuse for doing so.